# Accessing table cells with jQuery using an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, cell

I need to copy in a multidimensional array the cells of a table.
I try the following code:

```
function tableManager ( table, rowitems ) {
    var items = array () ;

    var j = 0 ;
    var arow = array() ;
    $(table+' td').each(function() {
        arow[j] = $(this).html() ;
        j ++ ;
        if ( j == rowitems) {
            items.push(arow);
            j = 0 ;
        } ;
   }) ;

    this.show = function() {
    .............
    }
}
```

constructor is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loadarr = new tableManager ( '#results', 4 ) ;
    ....
});
```

It seems do not execute the `each()` callback.

What is incorrect?

Comment: ```tableManager``` is a function not a class

Answer (score 0):

tableManager is a function, you don't have to construct it with "new". You have to call it as following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var loadarr = tableManager('#results', 4);
    ...
});
```

Also, you have a ";" after your "if(...){..}". You'll have to remove it :

```
if ( j == rowitems) {
        items.push(arow);
        j = 0 ;
    } ; <= REMOVE THIS
```

More details here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

André

Comment: Thanks. I try but it don't work. The code in function tableManager will be executed, with the exception of the each() callback

Comment: You have a ";" after your if(...){...}. You have to remove it (more details on my answer edit)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is:

> It seems do not execute the each() callback.

it is because `tableManager` is a function and you have to call it in the following way:

```
var loadarr = tableManager ( '#results', 4 ) ;
```

For more information visit [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Also, remove the `;` after the closing brace of the `if ( j == rowitems)`

```
if ( j == rowitems) {
    items.push(arow);
    j = 0 ;
} // Removed ;
```

---

**UPDATE**

If the `each` method isn't reached then try to understand what's happening. Try using

```
console.log($(table+' td'));
```

just before the `each` method to be shure that the latter isn't executing because there are no elements.

```
console.log($(table+' td'));
$(table+' td').each(function() {
    arow[j] = $(this).html() ;
    ...
```

Then you could add a `console.log("Each executed")` inside your parameter function to be shure that it is executed:

```
$(table+' td').each(function() {
    console.log("Each executed");

    arow[j] = $(this).html() ;
    j ++ ;
    if ( j == rowitems) {
        items.push(arow);
        j = 0 ;
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: Thanks. I try but it don't work. The code in function tableManager will be executed, with the exception of the each() callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery function is not correct please see Working code here

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table id="results">
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function tableManager ( table, rowitems ) {
                var items = [] ;

                $(table+' tr').each(function(i) {
                  var row = $(this);
                  if(rowitems == i){
                     row.find('td').each(function() {
                        console.log(this);
                        items.push($(this).html());
                     }) ; 
                  }
               });
                console.log(items);
               return items;
            }

      var itm = tableManager("#results", 4);
      console.log(itm);
    </script>
    </html>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! It helps so much. Few mods to adapt to my needs and it works